# replace document.getElementbyId("id") with just id

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

It seems that this code is working well. Please try it out before you answer:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Variables</h2>
<p>In this example, x, y, and z are variables.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
let x = 7;
let y = 45;
let z = x + y;
demo.innerHTML = "The value of z is: " + z;//please note this line
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this mean that I can replace document.getElementById("id"). with just id.???

Comment: You can't replace `document.getElementById("id")` with just `id`

Comment: It's working. So interesting

Comment: Yes it is. with all methods and not only with innerHTML. I haven't tested all browsers. Anyone know why is this happening? Is there a trap? I am a teacher. I have a class now with pupils that we re discussing getElementById. Do I tell them this???

Answer (score 0):

It's working but it's considered legacy and unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it does, and it works for nested elements also... I wonder though if it works on a different js file imported from the html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Variables</h2>
<p>In this example, x, y, and z are variables.</p>
<p id="demo1">
  <p id="demo2"></p>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
let x = 7;
let y = 45;
let z = x + y;
demo.innerHTML = "The value of z is: " + z;//please note this line

demo2.innerHTML = "The value of z is: " + z;//please note this line
console.log(demo);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```